# implementing listener for background activity android

Tags: android, interface

I am using **Data Droid library** to speed up asynchronous tasks. In data droid there is method similar to `onpostexecute` of async task.I am performing some async task using data droid for pre fetching of data. i want to implement listener for notifying the background process completion to another activity.can anyone clearly explain how to achieve this with interface.I have gone through many stackoverflow questions but still am unclear how to implement interface for this.

Comment: You will need to register a call back listener in the Another activity with the implemented method.

Comment: can u pls explain me how to implement listener for notifying about the completion of the background process in an activity to another activity.i saw many answer regarding this but i am still unclear.

Comment: which will be your front activity when you want to receiver completion Listener.

Comment: Login activity contains methods for async task. on completion of background process i have to notify the main class about the completion of background process.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity implements CompletionListener {
CompletionListener completionListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    completionListener=this;
}


class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        completionListener.onCompletion();
    }
}

}
```

let Your Activity extend this BaseActivity and MyTask is your Asynchronous Task then all the Activity extending this base class will receive a call from onPostExecute();

```
public interface CompletionListener {
public void onCompletion();
}
```